# Indesign: Frame on masterpage always on the front,

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

**Background:**

Our PIM system allows us to create a generated catalogue for our clients. For this client we are placing images on top of each other to create the illusion of items being displayed with a border due to the spread buildup of the image (it's being displayed over 2 pages, so we have to cut up the picture and put left side on the left page, and right side on the right page. (we can only generate page left or right, not both at the same time).

**Problem**

By overlaying these images, a certain text is dissapearing (placed below the image) which should be there. We been attempting to set in the master page the frame forward, but this is not taken in account by the software sadly, since in the master page, the image isnt placed yet. Is there a way we can "force" a frame to be always the first displayed from top, maybe via script label?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use Layers in InDesign** – also on Master pages.

So if, for example you want text to always be visible on top of images or backgrounds, you can place the text frame on a separate layer (stack layers accordingly: the layer at the top of the list is the topmost to be displayed).

[image: the Layers panel in InDesign]

A common use-case are page numbers: You usually place them on the master page, and want them to be visible, even when placing full bleed images in the layout.

I am interested to hear how others tackle this issue, perhaps there are way better methods.

Comment: Yes, this was our first thought as well, (we applied this to a different client as well) however, the client want as little as possible own actions in Indesign (lets say their marketing department dont have Indesign expertise in house). This is why i hoped that we can maybe do it via scriptlabel. Thanks for the feedback though, cause I am glad to read i am not the only one struggling with this.

Comment: If you put the text that is always disappearing onto a front layer in the master page, then lock this layer and let your client only always edit the "back" layer with the images that should not be of any more complexity than it its currently. The client would not even know that there is a front layer.

Comment: @mdomino, ha, yes that is exactly what I have done – until the client figured out how to unlock it, and started to mess everything up again.

Comment: Would it then still not be easier to tell the client to leave the locked front layer alone instead of implementing some complex scripting solution?